# How many numbers are there between $100$ and $1000$ such that every digit is either $2$ or $9$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many numbers are there between $100$ and $1000$ such that every digit is either $2$ or $9$?

I couldn't understand what actually the question means.  Does it talk about the numbers like $222$,  $999$?

Comment: Also $229$, $929$, and so on.

Comment: So, all the numbers between $100$ and $1000$ have 3 digits, right?
So what can the first digit be? What can the second and the third?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three digits. Each digit must be selected from the set $\{2,9\}$. You may select either of those two for each digit. So, the first digit has two choices. The second digit has two choices. The third digit has two choices. Each choice is independent of the previous choices. This allows you to apply the product principle.

There are $2\cdot 2\cdot 2=8$ such numbers:

222,
229,
292,
299,
922,
929,
992,
999